# Gelfand-Pettis integral: what does it mean for a topological vector space to "admit a dual space?"

Tags: rt.representation-theory, integration, topological-vector-spaces

I am trying to understand more about the Gelfand-Pettis integral.  From wikipedia:

[image]

What does it mean that $V$ "admits a dual space?"  When $V$ is a Banach space, $V^{\ast}$ is taken to be the space of bounded linear functionals on $V$.  When $V$ is a smooth (locally constant) representation of a totally disconnected group, $V^{\ast}$ is usually taken to mean the space of smooth linear functionals on $V$.

Is there a general notion of a topological vector space admitting a dual space?  Or is this just context dependent?

Comment: The key phrase seems to be "that separates points".

Comment: Every topological space admits a dual space (this is just the space of continuous, linear functionals). The full statement is "assume [...] admits a dual space which separates points." Not all topological vector spaces admit a dual space which separates points. For example, $L_\frac{1}{2}[0,1]$ has only two open, convex subsets (the empty set and the whole space). Thus there is a surprising lack of continuous, linear functionals on this space. Not enough to separate points.

Comment: I see, "dual space" for me means $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(V,\mathbb C)$, but I should take it to be the continuous functions.  Thank you.

Comment: In addition, "separates points" means that the original space embeds canonically into its *double* dual.

Comment: Yes, the dual of a **topological** vector space is (by convention) the set of all **continuous** linear functionals.  That is, when writing "Hom", you mean Hom in the category of topological vector spaces.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922567/difference-between-the-algebraic-and-topological-dual-of-a-topological-vector-sp/1922599#1922599